# Bank Withdraw and Deposit Program C#

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, readonly

I am new to C# and currently working on methods and constructors to create a simple bank withdrawal and deposit program to calculate the balance after.

I am either confused by these instructions given to me or I am doing something wrong. I just can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to set the initial default balance to $1000 while setting the Balance field as a read-only field.

The main problem I am having is that I am trying to set up a constructor for the read-only "Balance" field. C# is saying that I cannot call a method that is read-only. I posted my code below if anyone could help me. Thank you in advance.

**Account.cs**

```
class Account
{
    public const double defaultBalance = 1000;
    private double _amount;
    public double balance;

    public double Balance
    {
        get { return defaultBalance; }
    }

    public double Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return _amount;              
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Please enter an amount greater than 0");                  
            }
            else
            {
                _amount = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public double doDeposit()
    {          
        balance += _amount;
        return balance;
    }

    public double doWithdrawl()
    {
        balance -= _amount;

        if (balance < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Withdrawing " + _amount.ToString("C") + " would leave you overdrawn!");
        }
        return balance;
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
namespace Account_Teller
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Account acc = new Account();

    private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            acc.Amount = double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
            //Error in the line below. "Property cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
            //Trying to set the initial balance as $1000 using constructor from 'Account' class
            acc.Balance = double.Parse(lblBalance.Text);
            lblBalance.Text = acc.doWithdrawl().ToString("C");
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            acc.Amount = double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
            lblBalance.Text = acc.doDeposit().ToString("C");
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }    
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: You don't have a setter on your `Balance` property.

Comment: @Steve Instructions ask for me to set the Balance to a read-only property. Wouldn't be a problem if I was allowed to add a setter.

Comment: TLDR; I think you need something like `private decimal defaultBalance;`

Comment: Why is your getter for Balance returning the defaultBalance rather than the actual balance?

Also your trying to set the value of account.Balance on line you marked which. you should be parsing the acc.Balance into the text field

Comment: @NicholasTsaoucis So I was supposed to parse the label into a double then call the method account.Balance method? I attempted to do that, but am still getting an error "non-invocable member 'Account.Balance' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: It's bad design to have a setter for `Balance` anyway considering the nature of the program.  Any changes to `Balance` should be the result of _deposits; withdrawals; transfers; debits; credits_ and other forms of transactions to the `Account` object

Comment: Use `decimal` for monetary amounts and `double` for physical properties of things - like velocity or mass.

Comment: Balance **isn't** a method. It's a property. The error you're describing sounds like you're adding an argument list to it (`Balance()` would only work if this was VB.NET code).

Comment: @TiesonT. Yeah, i figured that out. I am either confused by these instructions given to me or I am doing something wrong. I just can't seem to figure it out even with all the help. I am trying to set the initial default balance to 1000 while setting the Balance field as a read-only field.

Comment: If in doubt why you should use decimal, try the following expression: "(0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3". It will evaluate to false while "(.1M + .2M) == .3M" evaluates to true as you would expect. The M tells the compiler your constant is a decimal instead of the default double type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A public attribute (property, field, delegate, event or method) should be always PascalCase
2. Instead of having an `Amount` attribute, you should pass it as parameter to the methods, I mean; `DoWithdraw(decimal amount)` and `DoDeposit(decimal amount)`
3. As I see, you want to be able to read `Balance` from outside the class, but only be able to modify it trought the class methods. The answer is to use auto-implemented properties; `public decimal Balance { get; private set; }`
4. Usually, an account doesn't have a default initial value, as Dax Fohl stated. It's more appropiate to have a constructor that let you set an initial value
5. Usually, we don't use "do" as prefix for infinitive verbs, just `Withdraw` and `Deposit`
6. As Dax and Lars said, it's more appropiate to use decimal data type for currencies

Then, your `Account` source code would be:

```
class Account {
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public Account(decimal initialBalance) {
        if(initialBalance < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The initial balance must be greater or equals to 0");
        this.Balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public bool TryDeposit(decimal amount) {
        if(amount <= 0)
            return false;
        this.Balance += amount;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryWithdraw(decimal amount) {
        if(amount <= 0 || this.Balance - amount < 0)
            return false
        this.Balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd put `DefaultBalance` into `Program.cs` or somewhere, and pass it into `Account` constructor.  It seems odd to have an account class that always starts with a set dollar amount (other than zero). Also `decimal` would be more apt than `double` here.

Comment: @TiesonT. As Balance setter should be private/protected, you wouldn't be able do that.

Comment: I recommend updating this answer to use decimal instead of double. Never let currency get anywhere near floating points. :)

Comment: @2niru Interesting. Was pretty sure I've done exactly that before, but...

Comment: @LarsMøllebjerg If you two say so. I didn't work with currencies before but I will assume that you're right.

Comment: I'd say `Withdraw` should be `bool TryWithdraw(decimal amount)`.  Throw an exception for bad (negative) input, but if there's not enough balance, that's not really an exception.  It's a normal case that should be handled in normal flow control.

Comment: In a real-world scenario that you use databases in non-observable patter, in memory data could be out of sync with the database. This method of coding doesn't protect the negative balance in a multi-thread situation (like a web or mobile app). It would cost you huge! You should find a better pattern to protect your bank app!

Comment: @DaxFohl - even `TryWithdraw()` doesn't protect causing negative-balance in a multi-threading situation...

Answer (score 0):

1) please change it in to console application with classes(deposit,withdraw,check balance,change pin)

2) please change it in to console application with classes(deposit,withdraw,check balance,change pin) & with using all OOP pillars